# How to seterror of textview

Tags: android

IN Edittext seterror working perfecty but  Textview  how to seterror

I tried coding so for

```
Textview  spinner = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_txt);
spinner_txt.setText(name);///from the coding i am setting settext
String spinnertxt=spinner.getText.toString;

if(spinnertxt.length()==0){
    spinner_txt.setError("select the representative");
    }
spinner_txt.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: oh dear! please check if you have initialized this spinner_txt

Answer (score 1):

```
Textview  spinner = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_txt);
```

`spinner_txt.setText(name);///from the coding i am setting settext`

Over here you are setting settext to **spinner_txt** instead of **spinner**. I wonder how is your setText is getting called.

```
String spinnertxt=spinner.getText.toString;
```

You are getting NullPointerException because your spinner textview does not contain any text and so, snippertxt is null and you are trying to get length of a null object.

Try this:-

```
spinner.setText(name);
String spinnertxt=spinner.getText.toString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually my question to seterror for textview....Like edit text ....
And my answer was
I found that edittext function work as  textview  by change the attrubutes in  xml. so keypad is not enable and focusableInTouchMode also false in android studio

```
android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```